# XMLHttpRequest.send(Int8Array) POST fails in Firefox only

Tags: firefox, xmlhttprequest, send

I'm trying to post data (a chunk of a file) using a `XmlHttpRequest` object with an `Int8Array` as the data but it fails in FF18, but works perfect in IE 10 & Chrome.

Here's my JS:

```
//dataObj is an Int8Array with approx. 33,000 items
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("POST", "Ajax/PostChunk");
oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
    //
};

oReq.send(dataObj);
```

I use Firebug in Firefox to debug my JS and when I watch the activity under the *Net* tab, nothing ever shows up for this XHR call. As if it was never called.

Also, prior to this call, I call jQuerys `.ajax()` method for "Ajax/PostChunkSize" and that works fine in all browsers, although that doesn't use an `Int8Array` for its data. I can't use `.ajax()` for this since `.ajax()` doesn't support `Int8Array` objects, as far as I know.

Does anyone know why Firefox doesn't even attempt to send this? Any questions, please ask.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ability to send a typed array (as opposed to an arraybuffer) is a recent addition to the in-flux XMLHttpRequest2 spec.  It'll be supported in Firefox 20 in April or so (see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=819741 ) but in the meantime if your Int8Array covers its entire buffer, doing `send(dataObj.buffer)` should work...

Note that per the old spec the code above should have sent a string that looks something like "[object Int8Array]" instead of throwing; you may want to check to make sure that other browsers really are sending the array data and not that string.

Comment: Thanks Boris, your workaround worked, kind of. Firefox is sending something, but not what it's suppose to. I'm not sending the entire ArrayBuffer since these files are going to be able to get pretty big, 100MB+. But I sliced the ArrayBuffer into a new ArrayBuffer of the same portion as I did with the Int8Array and FF is now sending something. I'm going to look into it more when I get the time, probably tomorrow.

Comment: I know for a fact it was working perfectly in IE10 and Chrome cause I've been doing file comparisons in WinHex between the saved file that ASP.NET generates based on the POST requests and the source file that I uploaded, and both files were the same size with each byte being identical.

Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: It works great, I had the end parameter of ab.slice() as a number representing the number of bytes I wanted, not the index of the end byte of the source ab like it was suppose to be, that was causing the problem of the wrong data. It's all good.